# Linear Regression Speed Increase

Tags: python, pytorch, linear-regression

I am new in  machine learning and it is my first time to create a linear regression model on a dataset(which is big step for me). I have created my reference rows and reshaped them. Only problem is  It is too slow. Is there an any code or better way that I can use. It would be great if you have chance to revise my code. 
Thank you.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import torch
import torch.nn as nn
import torch.nn.functional as F
from torch.utils.data import DataLoader
from torch.utils.data import TensorDataset
db = pd.read_csv("Melbourne_housing_FULL.csv")
db2 = pd.read_csv("MELBOURNE_HOUSE_PRICES_LESS.csv")

"""['Suburb', 'Address', 
'Rooms', 'Type', 'Price', 
'Method', 'SellerG',
'Date', 'Distance', 
'Postcode', 'Bedroom2', 'Bathroom', 'Car',
'Landsize', 'BuildingArea', 
'YearBuilt', 'CouncilArea', 
'Lattitude','Longtitude', 
'Regionname', 'Propertycount'] 

column names for Full.csv"""

rooms_properties = db[["Rooms","Landsize","Bathroom","Car","YearBuilt"]].copy()
rooms_properties.fillna(rooms_properties.mean(),inplace=True)
rooms_price = db[["Price"]].copy()
rooms_price.fillna(rooms_price.mean(),inplace=True)

room_array_properties = rooms_properties.to_numpy()
room_array_price = rooms_price.to_numpy()

##Splitted list with percentage
def indice_splitter(array_prop,x=0.2):
       val = np.random.permutation(len(array_prop))
       percent_1 = val[:int(len(val) * x)]
       percent_2 = val[int(len(val)*x):]
       return percent_2,percent_1
## Converted df as tensor

train_indices,validation_indices = indice_splitter(room_array_price)
train_data,targets1 = room_array_properties[train_indices], room_array_price[train_indices]

validation_data ,targets2 = torch.from_numpy(room_array_properties[validation_indices]).float(), torch.from_numpy(room_array_price[validation_indices]).float()
t_data, tar1 = torch.tensor(train_data,requires_grad=True).float(), torch.tensor(targets1,requires_grad=True).float()
# rooms_price = rooms_price[rooms_price.notnull()]
# r_nonull = [rooms_properties.loc[rooms_properties[i].notnull()]  for i in rooms_properties.columns]
# r_nonull = r_nonull[len(r_nonull)-1]
# r_array = r_nonull.to_numpy()

# weight = torch.rand(5,1, dtype=float,requires_grad=True)
# bias = torch.randn(len(train_data),dtype=float,requires_grad=True)

## my model and result
model = nn.Linear(5,1)
weight, bias = model.parameters()

train_ds = TensorDataset(t_data,tar1)
batch_size = 10
train_dl = DataLoader(train_ds,batch_size,shuffle=True)

preds = model(t_data)
loss_fn = F.mse_loss
opt = torch.optim.SGD(model.parameters(), lr= 1e-5)

#
def fit(num_epochs, model, loss_fn, opt):
       for epochy in range(num_epochs):
              for xb,yb in train_dl:
                     #increase the model accuracy
                     pred = model(xb)
                     loss = loss_fn(pred,yb)
                     loss.backward()
                     #upgrade the stoachaistic grad descent
                     opt.step()
                     #refresh the data
                     opt.zero_grad()
              if (epochy +1) % 10 == 0:
                     print("{}/{}, Loss:{:.4f}".format(epochy+1,num_epochs,loss.item()))

fit(10,model, loss_fn,opt)
```

### Output is = 10/10, Loss:nan

My expected output should decrease my loss function value every time.

I want to iterate this regression at least 1000 times.

I have 1660Ti , i7 9th Gen, 16gb ram laptop

Comment: you could look to vectorize your code by removing for loops. I am not an expert in machine learning but I do know in many cases it is possible to remove for loops and use certain operations in numpy or pandas. The double for loop is probably what is causing your code to be slow as it is probably a n^2 runtime.
You can read more about vectorization here: https://towardsdatascience.com/data-science-with-python-turn-your-conditional-loops-to-numpy-vectors-9484ff9c622e

Comment: @griffin_cosgrove I think the link is broken but I will check for it on intenet. Thank you.